# Secure communication between two iPhones

Tags: iphone, security, ios

I'm writing an iPhone application which will create p2p connection between two iPhones and allow devices to communicate with each other over Wi-Fi or BlueTooth.

Is it possible to secure the communication between two iPhones running my application?

Comment: There will be several different approaches to do this. One would be to encrypt all the data that is being send.

Comment: It won't be a problem to disassemble the application and determine the encryption method and key that are used in my application. Then a hacker will be able to sniff wireless traffic and read all the data. I'm looking for smth like Diffi-Hellman algorithm.

Comment: Also I would like to have authentication in order to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but thought I'd mention that Apple has a framework for this now with built-in crypto.

[Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity)